# Getting UFRAW into GIMP 2.8.14 on Yosemite

Tags: gimp

Folks claim that the versions of GIMP downloadable from http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Support.html have UFRAW in place. I just downloaded 2.8.14, and I see no sign of it. It's not listed in the plugin browser, and opening an NEF file opens a tiny thumbnail.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is there someplace else to get it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in UFRaw preventing it to work properly on Yosemite.
The recently (on 9th January 2015, that is) released GIMP 2.8.14p2 package now has a working UFRaw included.